# Coin flip, which way is would produce a more accurate 50%

Tags: math, random, swift3

I'm mostly curious on this, and it doesn't really matter that much, but given the these two blocks of code, which would more accurately produce a 50% probability?

```
let x = arc4random_uniform(2) //Between 0 & 1
let coin = x == 0 ? "heads" : "tails"

let x = arc4random_uniform(5000)
if x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2) == 0 {
   coin = "heads"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probabilistically they should be the same, since they both use `arc4random_uniform` which promises to give results where all outcomes are equally likely in the desired range.  However, the second one is going to do more work, both due to the modulo operation and because 5000 is not a power of 2 so [it will actually be doing some acceptance/rejection](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c) in the background to avoid [modulo bias](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/) and guarantee the uniformity of the `x`.  Stick with the first one.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Thank you

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

They both seem like they would be equally random to me. Maybe try running it on a loop to test it and record the answers.